# capture data from DropDownButton in flutter and send it to the database

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter app development and would like to ask for your help

I already learned to capture the data of a TextFormField but with the DropDownButtons I have no idea how it is I try to use controller to put a name but I get an error

I have a DropDownButton and it works for me, it is loading the list successfully and I would like to know, how to capture the data I select in the DropDownButton and send it to my database

This is the code that I am using:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _mySelection;
  final String url = "http://webmyls.com/php/getdata.php";
  List data = List();

  Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      data = resBody;
    });

    print(data);
    return "Sucess";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getSWData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new DropdownButton(
          //data != null,
          isDense: true,
          hint: new Text("Select"),
          items: data.map((item) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text(item['item_name']),
              value: item['id'].toString(),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newVal) {
            setState(() {
              _mySelection = newVal;
            });
          },
          value: _mySelection,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the latest dropdown value is always stores in your `_mySelection`. So the only thing you should do is to save `_mySelection` in your database.